# .NetCore 3.1 ManagementEventWatcherに代わる方法

Tags: c#, .net

現在、.Net Core 3.1 をターゲットとしたコンソールアプリケーションを作成しています。
そのなかで、USBの挿入/取り外しを検出する為、以下のようにしています。

```
public void BeginMonitor()
{
    ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(); 
    WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2 or EventType = 3");
    watcher.EventArrived += Watcher_EventArrived;
    watcher.Query = query;
    watcher.Start();

    while(true)
    {
        AuthenticationMock();
        watcher.WaitForNextEvent();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}

private void Watcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    string driveName = e.NewEvent.Properties["DriveName"].Value.ToString();
    EventType eventType = (EventType)Convert.ToInt16(e.NewEvent.Properties["EventType"].Value);
    string eventName = Enum.GetName(typeof(EventType), eventType);

    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}: {driveName} {eventName}");
}
```

しかし、ManagementEventWatcherを使用するにはSystem.Managementを参照する必要があります。
これはMicrosoftの推奨しないシナリオと考えています。
[(MSDNより)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/using-wmi)
代替として、Microsoftが推奨しているMicrosoft.Management.Infrastructureを使用するべきと思っていますが、その場合ManagementEventWatcherの様な動作を実現する方法が分かりません。ポーリングして監視する方法ではなく、イベントフックで処理を行うようにしたいと考えています。

CimSessionを使用してOSやBIOS情報の取得等は出来たのですが、イベントについてはあまり記述が見当たらず、行き詰っております。参考となるドキュメントなどありましたら、ご教示お願いします。

Comment: MSDNのどこで言及されているのかリンクを示してください。

Comment: @sayuri  リンクを追加しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`CimSession.SubscribeAsync`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wmi_v2/mi-managed-api/hh832612(v=vs.85))を用いれば実現できると思います:

```cs
var session = CimSession.Create(null);

session.SubscribeAsync(
    "ROOT\\CIMV2", "WQL", "SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2 or EventType = 3"
).Subscribe(e =>
{
    string driveName = e.Instance.CimInstanceProperties["DriveName"].Value as string;
    // do something
});
```

`Win32_VolumeChangeEvent`自体については詳しくないので、処理の中身については未回答です。

Comment: .SubscribeはIObserver<T>を要求するため、独自のObserverに置き換えて試したところ、検知出来ました。また、「Win32_VolumeChangeEvent 」を「Win32_DeviceChangeEvent」としました。なぜかUSBの抜き差し時に複数回呼び出される現象が発生していますが、動作に支障は無い為そのままとしています。